# Failed to start instance: A e2-micro VM instance is currently unavailable in the us-central1-a zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am facing this issue from yesterday. This is the exact error: Failed to start feature-config: A e2-micro VM instance is currently unavailable in the us-central1-a zone. Alternatively, you can try your request again with a different VM hardware configuration or at a later time. For more information, see the troubleshooting documentation.

[image: This is the error that I get:-]

I had scheduled Google Compute Engine to TURN on & off at specific time using Instance scheduler but now I am locked out of it. I cannot even create a machine image to deploy on another zone

Comment: What do you mean locked out?

Comment: I cannot open this instance. Happening from yesterday for US Central Zone

Comment: Again, be specific. Specify what you are doing and the error. Are you unable to log into the Google Cloud Console?

Comment: I am trying to open instance manually. Earlier I had scheduled this instance and it used to work fine before.

I am able to login to Cloud Console but when I try to open Compute Instance via SSH , it shows the above error message

Comment: The error means that there is no resource available for that instance size in that zone. I sometimes can start an instance after selecting a larger machine type. The small ones are in high demand. Otherwise search Stack Overflow. This problem has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: What worked? Please provide more details on the solution.

Comment: I changed the Machine Configuration. As from your answer I could figure out that resources might not be available for the US Central Zone possibly due to traffic. I changed configuration to - n2-highcpu-2 vCPU 2  & Memory -2 GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the Machine Configuration. As from your answer I could figure out that resources might not be available for the US Central Zone possibly due to traffic. I changed configuration to - n2-highcpu-2 vCPU 2 & Memory -2 GB

Comment: Is trial and error seriously the only way to figure out what combinations of hardware and location are viable?

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue here, but coming from a terraform apply. I've tried multiple zones and every one says both 'e2-small' and 'e2-micro' instances are unavailable.  Seems google completely fumbled the "cloud game" here since AWS doesn't have this problem EVER!  (not that I like using AWS, it's just "ick" compared to google).

Answer (score 0):

At the end, it seems this was a general issue that multiple users experienced in `us-central1` among other regions.

In this [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260280330) more is talked and it seems it got worse during the weekend.

As some suggestions in the comments, changing the zone/region/hardware can help but not always since this also depends on any constraints you may have.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, there aren't any available resources in that regions. I contacted GCP support after facing the same issue and got the following response:

> Google Cloud Support, : Upon further checking, the reason that the e2-medium VM instance is currently unavailable is because there are limited VMs available to a specific zone and regions. Best we can do is to try another time or select a different zone so that the VMs that you desire to use will start. Rest assured that there is nothing wrong with your account and it was on the us-central1 zone who do not have available VMs you selected as of the moment.

If possible, try deploying to a different instance. For those who need an instance in `us-central1` (for Qwiklabs?) might have to wait until more instances are available.